# Dot product two lists containing pure functions

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

Can i get something like this to work?

```
{D[#1, t] & , D[#1, x] & } . {t, y}
```

and my expected output be

```
{D[#1, t] &[t], D[#1, x] &[y]}
```

basically just a dot product with pure functions in one list and i get a list with derivatives.Right now,i just get this

```
t*(D[#1, {t}] & ) + y*(D[#1, {x}] & )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This?

```
Inner[Construct, {D[#1, t] &, D[#1, x] &}, {t, y}, List]
```